# Karate - How to get one cucumber report generated instead of one for each feature file

Tags: karate

In my Karate runner I am using .outputCucumberJson(true) as shown below to generate a Cucumber Report (in order to upload this back to our XRAY tests):

```
class KarateRunnerTest {

    @Test
    void testParallel() {
        Results results = Runner.path("classpath:apiTesting/karateFeatureFiles/")
                .outputCucumberJson(true)
                .parallel(5);
        assertEquals(0, results.getFailCount(), results.getErrorMessages());
    }

}
```

However, it is producing one report for each Feature File.
Is there a way for it to just generate one report for all Feature Files?

Comment: no. you are welcome to contribute code. to be honest only 2 or 3 people have asked this question ever, so we don't consider it needed or a priority

Answer (score 0):

So this currently can't be done in Karate.

As a workaround I used a little npm tool called 'cucumber-json-merge'.

This merged the reports into 1 and seems to work fine.